# Pushes done by Pycharm or the terminal are not being counted in the commit calender of github

Tags: github, version-control, pycharm, git-commit

I am using pycharm on windows 10 home edition and whenever I push a the commit , the commit is shown on the website but not on the commit calender

When I click on one of the repos created by pycharm , and then click on `commits` , I can see my name but there's no picture of mine beside my name . On the other hand when I make changes through the website itself like making a readme ; the calender gets updated and if i go in the `commits` tab I can see my display picture beside my name.

What do I do to update the calender on pushes done by pycharm

Comment: Your title mentions github but your tags were for gitlab; I changed the tag, but I'm not really sure which one was wrong.

Comment: sorry my bad , IT IS GITHUB

Comment: @MrHola21 did you managed to find solution ?

Comment: @Zhenia using the new version of pycharm, I am not facing any problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set an author to your commits? It could be that your username in the global git config is not github username or mail which could give Github a hard time to link the commit with your user profile.

As an alternative you could login with your GitHub Account directly in PyCharm. To do so go to Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub.

Comment: I am already logged in with my github account on pycharm